# Finiteness of the space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

In my particular case, suppose that $X$ is a curve smooth (and other good adjectives.) over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$  and $G$ be a divisor.

The space $L_k(G)=\{\mathbb F_q (X):(f)+G\geq 0\}$ is a sub-space of $L(G)=\{\overline{\mathbb F_q}(X):(f)+G\geq 0\}$.

$L_k(G)$ is a finite set right?

Or we should add some hypothesis in G?

Comment: Do you mean "$L_k(G) = \{ f \in \mathbb{F}_q(X) \ : \ (f)+G\ge 0 \}$" ?

Comment: Yes right......

Comment: I'm not an expert of finite field, but if $G=0$, then for all $n$ you have $X^n\in L_k(G)$ right ?